# Node Worker threads with Typescript and "code":"ERR_REQUIRE_ESM" while upgrading angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to upgrade the angular on a Node 14 Typescript codebase that uses worker threads. After upgrading to Angular 12 and above, the ts-node command fails with a

> "code":"ERR_REQUIRE_ESM" .... require() of ES Module.

The only place I have used a require is to compile the worker thread as suggested in the article [here](https://wanago.io/2019/05/06/node-js-typescript-12-worker-threads/).

Here is the snippet of the code where required is used. The file extension for this is a .js.

```js
const path = require("path");

require("ts-node").register();
require(path.resolve(__dirname, "./process-query-fork.ts"));
```

I have tried answers from previous similar questions and changing the version of typescript, ts-node, node-fetch etc. and nothing has worked.

Here's my package.json file

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.4.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "dd-trace": "^0.30.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.11.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "ldapjs": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mongodb": "^4.13.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mustache": "^4.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "seedrandom": "^3.0.5",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.7.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/dateformat": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "@types/mustache": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.1",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.7",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/seedrandom": "^2.4.28",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.11",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.33",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.9.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "socket.io-mock": "^1.3.2",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
```

Is there anything else I could try?